# Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn comes out as I�t�rn�ti�n�liz�ti�n on javascript page

Tags: javascript

I'm taking in a csv file, which includes the test value 'Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn' and outputting it to a simple HTML table using JavaScript.

The table displays the output as  I�t�rn�ti�n�liz�ti�n.  I've been looking on the web and have tried the suggestions of changing font & also charset (tried UTF-8, UTF-16, windows-1252, iso 8859-1 & iso 8859-5) but nothing works.

It's a drag and drop that takes in the csv and changes it into an HTML table on the webpage and uses xml to output a word document of the same table.

Sorry, I should have said:- There is no PHP on this page, it all takes place in the local browser, hence JavaScript.  Also, I don't have control over the coding of the files being used or the settings in the user's browser. Most of my users are going to be making this file in excel, I suspect.

Here is the code:

```
  <div id="drop_zone">Drop files here</div>
<output id="list"></output>

<script type="text/javascript" >

var URLadd = "My url here";
var OutString = [];
var TestFunc = [];
function handleFileSelect(evt) { // function 1 bracket
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.
    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = []; 
    oForm = document.forms[0]; 
    oText = oForm.elements["Inst"];
    var InstCode = oText.value;
   if (InstCode == "")
   {
    InstCode = "<b>Please enter your institution code</b>";
   }
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) { // loop 1
      if (f.name.match('\.csv')) { // if 1
      // this part is for when a csv file is drag n dropped
    var Filename = decodeURI(escape(f.name));
        var reader = new FileReader();
        // when the file loads, the function beneath is run   
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) { // function 2

           // this function is executed before it is returned, by the last parenthesis (f)         
       return function(e) { //function 3            
         var contents = e.target.result;
        var FileLines = contents.split( "\n" );
        var LineCount = FileLines.length;
        OutString = '<table id="mytab" border="1" width="100%"><tr>';
        var ColCount = 1;
        for (var i=1; i<LineCount; ++i)
        { // loop 2

         if (ColCount>4)
            {ColCount=0;}
         if(ColCount==0)
           { // if 2
              OutString += '</tr><tr>';
              ColCount = 1;
           } // close if 2
         OutString += '<td width=25%>';
         var CommaSplit = FileLines[i].split(",");
         var CommaCount = CommaSplit.length;
                          if (CommaCount == 5)
                  { // if 3
                      OutString += "<strong> " + CommaSplit[0] + " " + CommaSplit[1] + "</strong><br>";
                      OutString += "Username: " + CommaSplit[3] + "<br>Password: " + CommaSplit[3];
                      OutString += "<br>Institution Code: " + InstCode + "<br>"  + URLadd;

                      ColCount += 1;

                  } else { // else of if 3
                     for (var j= 0; j<CommaCount; ++j)
                     { // loop 3
                         OutString +=   CommaSplit[j] + '<br>';
                         ColCount += 1;
                     } // close loop 3
                } //close if 3
                  OutString += '</td>';

        } // close loop 2
        OutString += '</tr></table>';
        TestFunc = '<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" ';
            TestFunc += 'xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" ';
            TestFunc += 'xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" ';
            TestFunc += 'xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" ';
            TestFunc += 'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">';
            TestFunc += '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta><title>Passwords Doc</title>';
            TestFunc += '<style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}.shape behavior:url(#default#VML);}</style>';
            TestFunc += '<style>@page{mso-page-orientation: landscape; size:29.7cm 21cm; margin:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;}';
            TestFunc += '@page Section1 {mso-header-margin:0in; mso-footer-margin:0in; mso-header: h1; mso-footer: f1; }';
            TestFunc += ' div.Section1 { page:Section1; }';
            TestFunc += 'table#mytab{ margin: 0.2in 0.2in 0.2in 0.2in; width:0px; height:0px; overflow:hidden;}';

             TestFunc += '</style><xml><w:WordDocument><w:View>Print</w:View><w:Zoom>100</w:Zoom><w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>';
            TestFunc += '</w:WordDocument></xml></head><body><div class="Section1">';
            TestFunc += OutString;
            TestFunc += '</div></body></html>';
            var OutPutLine = "<a href='data:application/msword;charset=UTF-8, " + encodeURIComponent(TestFunc) + "' download='" + decodeURIComponent(escape('Login Slips.doc')) + "' ><input id='Button1' type='button' value='Open printable sheet' /></a>";
            output.push(OutPutLine);  
            document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';    
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = [OutString].join('');
        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);    

       }; // close function 3

        })(f); // close function 2
        reader.readAsText(f);         
         // this creates the button that opens the finished document    
        //var OutPutLine = "<a href='WordTemplate.doc' ><input id='Button1' type='button' value='Open printable sheet' /></a>";
              output.push(OutPutLine);   

      } else { // else of if 1
       // this triggers if its not a csv file that drag n drops
           output.push('<strong>', escape(f.name), ' is not a comma seperated (.csv) file!!!!</strong>');
      }     // close if 1          
    } // close loop 1  
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
} // close function 1

  function handleDragOver(evt) { // function 4
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
  } // close function 4

  // Setup the dnd listeners.
  var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
  dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Have you done everything listed here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through, [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: The � characters indicate an invalid byte in a string that's interpreted as UTF-8. This means your base string of bytes (coming from a file or the database) is physically stored in a legacy encoding (like ISO-8895-1) and forcibly interpreted as UTF-8 later-on. Change your file encoding by opening it in a text editor and re-saving it as UTF-8. This will of course not reliably help if there are more encoding mistakes in your processing chain.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said:- I don't have control over the coding of the files being used or the settings in the user's browser. Most of my users are going to be making this file in excel, so I guess I'm looking for a way of programmatically converting to utf-8, if that turns out to be the solution.

Comment: The � characters mean that the string already is broken. Nothing you can do with HTTP headers or whatnot will help you at this point. The string will remain broken. You must identify the point in your processing chain that breaks the string. `reader.readAsText(f);` looks suspicious. Try `reader.readAsText(f, "Windows-1252");`.

Comment: Tomalak, that worked brilliantly! Put it in as an answer and I will gladly accept it. Thank you.